# Show that $\exp(\sin z)$ has an antiderivative on $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

How can we show that $\exp(\sin z)$ has an antiderivative on $\mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 2):

$\exp{w}$ is an analytic function in $\mathbb{C}$ and therefore has a Maclurin series valid for all $w \in \mathbb{C}$:

$$\exp{w} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{w^k}{k!}$$

$w = \sin{z}$ is also an analytic function in $\mathbb{C}$:

$$w = \sin{z} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{z^{2 n+1}}{(2 n+1)!}$$

One may derive a single series for the composite function, valid for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

$$\exp{(\sin{z})} = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} a_m z^m$$

This series may be integrated term by term because it represents an analytic function for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$:

$$\int dz \, \exp{(\sin{z})} = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_m}{m+1} z^{m+1}$$

The series on the right represents the antiderivative of $\exp{(\sin{z})}$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Conventionally, symbol $\mathbb C$ means the complex numbers without infinity.

Comment: Maybe next time I discuss a real-variable problem, I will talk about $\mathbb R \setminus \{i\}$.

Comment: @GEdgar: ha!  I'd like to see you do that.

Comment: There is no need to discuss the series, really: the  integral you wrote defines an antiderivative! (One has to check that it is well defined, surely)

Answer (score 1):

A function has an antiderivate when it is analytic on a simply connected region, and the composition of analytic functions is analytic. As $\mathbb{C}$ is simply connected and $\exp(\sin(z))$ is analytic it has an antiderivative.

Comment: You need to be careful here. Every holomorphic function having a primitive is equivalent to the domain of definition being simply connected. Here we are fine because $\mathbb{C}$ is simply connected.

Comment: yeah i will add it